# PostgreSQL Cross Server query through SSH tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh-tunnel

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.18. I have two servers lets call the server1 and ssh_server. I connect to ssh_server via SHH tunnel. In a SELECT statement, I need to JOIN with a table in ssh_server from server 1. With normal connections I would use db_link with such connection string

```
select dblink_connect(‘dev1’, ‘host=dev1 user=myUser password=myPassword dbname=myDb’);
```

But I don't know if it's possible/how to connect through SSH with dblink.

Any idea would be appreciated

I tried to run the following on cmd:
`ssh -L 5433:DBhost:5432 db_user@SSH Server`

But I get the following error message:

SSh: connect to host hostname port 22: connection timed out.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you intend to use the tunnel for, or even that you intend to tunnel at all.  You are failing before either of those things come in to play. You say you  "connect to ssh_server via SHH tunnel" but here you fail.  So when you do it successfully, what is different?